# Powershell V2 - Logging remove-item

Tags: logging, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I've seen a few answers to similar problems however I cannot get any of them to work. Probably as I'm using V2 of powershell and cannot redirect streams. My question is simple, I wish to log the verbose stream of remove-item cmdlet in the following script:

```
$CSVList = (Get-Content "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\Test folder\Watchfolder\DAZN Production Numbers - purgelist.csv" | select -Skip 1) -split ','| Where {$_}

$Netappdirectory = "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\Test folder\NetApp"
$Logfile = "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\Test folder\logfile.txt"

Get-ChildItem $Netappdirectory |
  Where-Object {$CSVList -contains $_.BaseName} |
  Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell v2 allows only redirection of the Success (STDOUT) and Error (STDERR) output streams. [Redirection for other streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) is [not available prior to PowerShell v3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/). Also, `Remove-Item` doesn't have a parameter for defining a variable for verbose (or debug) output, so you can't capture that output in a variable like you can with warning and error output.

Your best option if you can't upgrade to PowerShell v3 or newer is probably creating a [transcript](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687007.aspx) of the operation:

```
Start-Transcript $Logfile -Append
Get-ChildItem $Netappdirectory | ... | Remove-Item -Verbose
Stop-Transcript
```

Otherwise you would need to run the operation in a separate PowerShell process. Additional streams of external processes are mangled into the Success and Error output streams (STDOUT, STDERR) when the output is returned to the parent process.

```
powershell.exe -Command "&{Get-ChildItem $Netappdirectory | ... | Remove-Item -Verbose}" >> $Logfile
```

That's a pretty ugly approach, though, so I wouldn't recommend it.

---

**Side note:** Even PowerShell v2 has an `Import-Csv` cmdlet, so I fail to see why you would want to emulate it via `Get-Content` and `-split`.